# How to work with alias in JPQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2, jpql

I'm trying to get some values from a H2 db table.
The query which does what I need is this:

```
SELECT cast(creationDate as date) as DATE, SUM(paymentValue) as TOTAL,fxRate 
FROM payment 
group by DATE
```

where "creationDate", "paymentValue", "fxRate" are columns of the table "payment". 
CreationDate is a timestamp so I have to get only the date from it.
When I try to write it in Java

```
 @Query("SELECT cast(creationDate as date) as daydate , SUM(paymentValue) as value1, fxRate as value2 FROM payment " + 
            "group by cast(creationDate as date)")
    List<Payment> findPaymentValuePerDay ();
```

I get the error `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ...entity.Payment.`

I also tried to use a different object called GraphDto which has as attributes daydate, value1 and value2

```
@Query("SELECT cast(creationDate as date) as daydate , SUM(paymentValue) as value1, fxRate as value2 FROM payment " + 
            "group by cast(creationDate as date)")
    List<GraphDto> findPaymentValuePerDay ();
```

but I get the same error.

```
 [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ...entity.GraphDto.
```

so, how can I work with alias in JPQL?? I just need a function that returns 3 different columns' name with values took from an existing entity using the right H2 query.
Thank you all

Comment: When you are trying to select `cast(creationDate as date) as daydate , SUM(paymentValue) as value1, fxRate as value2`, you are trying the cast `Object[]` to `GraphDto`. No wonder you get an error. You have to parse the `Object[]` element by element, or create a suitable constructor in `GraphDto`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query return an array of `Object[]` and not `GraphDto` Object, you have multiple ways to solve this problems :

### Solution 1

Create a constructor which hold `daydate`, `value1`, `value2`

```
@Entity
public class GraphDto{

    private Date daydate;
    private Long value1;
    private Long value2;

    public GraphDto(Date daydate, Long value1, Long value2){
        //...
    }
    //..getters and setters
}
```

then your query should look like this :

```
SELECT NEW com.packagename.GraphDto(cast(creationDate AS date), SUM(paymentValue), fxRate)
FROM payment
GROUP BY cast(creationDate AS date)
```

### Solution 2

change the return type to :

```
List<Object[]> findPaymentValuePerDay ();
```

Then in your service loop over this object and extract the values :

```
List<Object[]> listObject = rep.findPaymentValuePerDay();
for(Object[] obj : listObject){
   Date date = (Date) obj[0];
   Long value1 = (Long) obj[1];
   Long value2 = (Long) obj[2];
}
```

Comment: another possible solution is List<Map<String, Object>> findPaymentValuePerDay()