# Converting query result to Entity - Spring Boot/JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called forumUser that has several attributes. I want to make custom query and get only the id as a forumUser and leave the rest of attributes so I later add it to different services and dtos. The issue is that when I return the custom query, it cannot be converted to my entity ForumUser.

Query:

```
   @Query("SELECT p.id FROM ForumUser p WHERE LOWER(p.username) = LOWER(:username) ")
ForumUser find(@Param("username") String username);
```

Error:

```
java.util.UUID cannot be cast to com.example.demo.Entity.ForumUser
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep it forumUser?

Comment: yes create a constructor which hold a p.id or return all the object p!

Comment: Can you give an example as answer

Comment: try like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-native-query-result-to-non-entity-pojo   so that map the result to the entity so while fetch you will get an exact entity like resultset mapping

Comment: You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677700/how-to-work-with-alias-in-jpql/50677919#50677919 I provide two solutions hope this can help you :)