# How to use alias in JPQL?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am working on **Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE and Spring Data JPA**. I want to convert below SQL into JPQL

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(orderDate) AS year,
    SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) AS total
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN orderdetails 
    USING (orderNumber)
WHERE
    status = 'Shipped'
GROUP BY 
    year
HAVING 
    year > 2003;
```

Error

```
2019-12-27 11:23:43.077  WARN 1536 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2019-12-27 11:23:43.077 ERROR 1536 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'order0_.orderDate' in 'having clause'
2019-12-27 11:23:43.084  INFO 1536 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-27 11:23:43.094 ERROR 1536 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringBootJpaMysqlComplexApplication.main(SpringBootJpaMysqlComplexApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.findByYearAndSumAndHaving(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.SpringBootJpaMysqlComplexApplication.run(SpringBootJpaMysqlComplexApplication.java:39) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'order0_.orderDate' in 'having clause'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

I used below query, but look like Alias is not creating and hence unable to use that.

```
@Query("SELECT YEAR(o.orderDate) AS YEAR, SUM(od.quantityOrdered * od.priceEach) AS amount FROM Order o "
            + "INNER JOIN o.orderdetails od WHERE o.status='Shipped' GROUP BY YEAR(o.orderDate) HAVING YEAR(o.orderDate) > 2003")
    List<Object[]> findByYearAndSumAndHaving();
```

OrderDetail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orderdetails")
@NamedQuery(name="Orderdetail.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Orderdetail o")
public class Orderdetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderdetailPK id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private short orderLineNumber;

    @Column(nullable=false, precision=10, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal priceEach;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int quantityOrdered;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orderNumber", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Order order;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Product
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="productCode", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Product product;
    ...
    ....
}
```

Comment: Entity class added

Comment: There are no aliases in JPQL. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677700/how-to-work-with-alias-in-jpql

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I saw such links few times and as per my knowledge Alias works in JPQL. This works for me `@Query("SELECT MAX(o.orderLineNumber) AS Total FROM Orderdetail o ORDER BY Total")`

Comment: But the question is why do you want aliases? They make no sense. Becuase you cannot use them anywhere to get the data from the result

Comment: Aliases at the class level works and based on that we can pull the data, however I want to do the same for the logical queries like I asked, so need to use Entity Manager and use native query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204925/discussion-between-simon-martinelli-and-paa).

Comment: Use JPA Criteria API and DTO projection.

Comment: @AshishBakwad - Could you please show sample example ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example for JPA Criteria API

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ResultDTO> cq = cb.createQuery(ResultDTO.class);

// Define FROM clause

Root<Orderdetail> root = cq.from(Orderdetail.class);

Join<Orderdetail, Order> order = root.join("order", JoinType.INNER);

cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("status"), "Shipped"));

cq.groupBy(root.get("orderDate"));

cq.having(cb.gt(cb.function("YEAR", Integer.class, root.get("orderDate")), 2003));

cq.select(cb.construct(ResultDTO.class, 
   cb.function("YEAR", Integer.class, root.get("orderDate")), 
   cb.sum(cb.prod(root.get("quantityOrdered"), order.get("priceEach")))
));
cq.distinct(true);

TypedQuery<ResultDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq).setHint(QueryHints.HINT_READONLY, true);

// Execute query
return query.getResultList();

public class ResultDTO {

  private Integer year;
  private Long total;

  public ResultDTO(Integer year, Long total) {

              .....

  }

  //getter setter

}
```